# How to extract the handwritten text from a user filled form(image)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have a form with the printed text and handwritten text combined ( user filled form),
i want to extract the text which is handwritten whether it is blue inked or black inked.

[image: example 1]

Comment: How many data of these kind do you have?

Comment: It is of different type forms

Comment: So it's a hard problem. If you have lots of images (e.g more than 300 images) the best way is to use object detection methods like YOLO to find the desired handwritten parts.

Comment: Is it possible to use yolo if i have same type of forms

Comment: Yes, yolo works best for the problem.

Comment: @MH304 i have tried to segment the handwritten text part from the form which all the forms have same type with 40-50 samples but yolo failed to detect, any other options?

Comment: This problem need so many trial and error. You should try tesseract library (which is specified for text detection). The other way is to removing the table lines using Hough Transform then try to locate other curves (texts)

Comment: My forms are not same as the one i have poster. Actual form don't have any lines

Comment: Exploit Tesseract. It's good enough.